# See if a transformation is linear by the shapes the basis vectors make

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Having just recently learned about linear transformations in class, I figured I would ask my question here since my prof. gave a vague answer.

So thinking of a linear transformation as a change of coordinate system rather than manipulating the vector itself and keeping the Cartesian system, I've got a question.

Bear with me, I'm not sure how to word this problem with the limited knowledge of linear algebra.

Let's say you're given the two standard vectors $e_1 = \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$ and $e_2 = \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$.

Given a transformation $T$, is there a way of seeing if the transformation is linear by looking at the shapes vectors create?

If you look at the picture below it better illustrates my question.

[Transformation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFjdk.png)

Comment: I don't fully understand your question...  all linear transformations *are linear transformations*.  Now, if you aren't sure if your transformation is linear or not, then just knowing $T(e_1)$ and $T(e_2)$ etc... is not enough information to tell whether or not it is linear, and "*looking at the shapes vectors create*" can't possibly cover all of the infinitely many possibilities.  Remember the definition of what it means to be a linear transformation, that for any $\alpha,u,v$ that you have $T(\alpha u + v) = \alpha T(u)+T(v)$.  That has nothing to do with the "shapes" made.

Comment: It seems that what you’re really looking at is the image of the grid (lattice) created by holding one coordinate fixed while varying the other. Eyeballing this image can certainly give you a clue as to linearity, but to be sure you still have to verify analytically. You also need to examine the image of the origin: as you’ve illustrated the idea, there’s no way to tell if you’ve actually got an _affine_ transformation instead.

Comment: I guess I'm not sure how to word the question. A visualization for adding vectors $a$ and $b$ is moving the "tail" of $a$ to the tip of $b$ and vice versa. And with the standard vectors the shape that these 4 vectors create together is a square. But that second image doing the same thing with the standard vectors creates a parallelogram. My question was looking at just the parallelogram(or whatever other shape it can create) is there a way to see if the transformation is linear.